# Having fixed-size widgets inside a layout in Qt Window

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt, so I started a project to practice using the library. I have window with two controls:

- List widget (on the top)
- Graphics view (on the bottom)

They are grouped in the `centralWidget` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>660</width>
    <height>412</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>100</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>100</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>660</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The controls are growing with the window, but they are not resizing as I need to. So I've read the documentation from the Qt site, nothing clear. Below is a video of how the window is resized.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDSxcKFILOE

Please watch it to be able to clearly understand what the problem is.

**How should things happen?**

When I horizontally resize the window, everything is already working fine, both controls grow/shrink with the window. When I resize the window vertically, the only control that should resize is the one at the top (the ListView).  The graphics view has to be of size `width: as the listview, height: 100`

Answer (score 0):

First see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum

What you need to (and appear to be doing) is to set the policy to `QSizePolicy::Fixed`. However, in your video it shows that the widget still shrinks in some situations.

To avoid this, make sure that all the three widgets in the scene have appropriate minimum sizes set.

- Set the minimum size of your widget to the same as the maximum size.
- Maybe remove a high minimum size of the other widget.
- If needed, set a minimum size for the parent widget.

Sometimes Qt's layouting gets quite tricky until you get what you want.